# How can I count with longer floats?

Tags: python, count, digits, pi

I'm programing Python code for counting pi to lot of digits, but python allow me count only on 16 digits. (Despite fact that 12345**12345 is not problem to count, it isn't fair.) Is it possible to count with higher exactness? Exist some object, witch one is able to certain more digits? 
Code here:

```
def fl(x):
    if x < 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return x*fl(x - 1)
per = int (input("Period: "))
k = 0
x = 1
while k < per:
    x += (fl(6*k)*(13591409 + 545140134*k))/(fl(3*k)*((fl(k))**3)*((-640320)**(k*3)))
    print(x)
    k += 1

print("pi: " + str(426880*(10005**0.5)/x))
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/decimal

Comment: @mata `Decimal` still has a max precision, and the OP is probably also having frustrations with the fact that `print` truncates and does scientific notation for numbers by default.

Comment: @yes, of course it has a max precision, there isn't a floating point implementation that hasn't, but that precision is tuneable.

Comment: It looks, though, like what the OP wants is a function that will accurately calculate the value of an arbitrary digit of pi given it's position in the value using a calculation that doesn't require the context of the rest of the number.  He'd probably be better off just storing or printing each digit or every 5 or 10 digits individually, thus being able to dynamically and accurately represent arbitrary precision, rather than trying to use another precision-limited datatype to store the entire value.

Answer (score 1):

There are three common libraries that provide extended precision floating point.

Decimal is included in all recent versions of Python. Prior to Python 3.3, it was relatively slow, but in Python 3.3, it was implemented in C and is much faster. Decimal has the advantage of being included with all recent versions of Python.

[mpmath](https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) is a pure Python library that implements an extended precision data type. mpmath has the advantage of being written in pure Python.

[gmpy2](https://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) is a Python wrapper for the GMP/MPIR, MPFR, and MPC extended precision libraries. gmpy2 is the fastest for most calculations, but requires extra effort to install on Mac or Linux systems. (Windows binaries are available, however.)

Disclaimer: I maintain gmpy2 and have worked on mpmath.